# WPF Создание template для кнопок с индивидуальными картинками

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xml, wpf-шаблоны

У меня есть кнопки, у которых должен быть один стиль. Я создал его, используя template. Но у каждой кнопки своя картинка и я не понимаю как указать в Image свойство Source, чтобы при создании кнопки в xml окна, можно было указать source индивидуально.

Comment: В таких случаях делают свой контрол, со своим новым свойством, ну либо городят костыли, используя другие свойства для этой задачи (контент, тег, и др.).

Answer (score 0):

Меня спас TemplateBinding

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,1" EndPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```